# Protect specific directories with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, access-control

Is it possible to protect specific directories with a single .htaccess and .htpasswd file?

I can only seam to find the ability to protect single files, or an entire directory (and it's sub directories)?

E.g .htpasswd in /public_html/myfolder

and protect

/public_html/myfolder/secret
/public_html/myfolder/admin

but not

/public_html/myfolder/mypublicfiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

htaccess files are a per directory options, it's sort of like a `<Directory>` block but defined by where you put the htaccess file. So you can't arbitrarily setup HTTP authentication on a directory other than the directory that the htaccess file is in.